# PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage suddenly giving empty string

Tags: c#, pdf, ssis, itext

We've been using the iTextSharp libraries for a couple of years now within an SSIS process to read some values out of a set of PDF exam documents.  Everything has been running nicely until this week when suddenly we are getting the return of an empty string when calling the PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage method.  I'll include the code here:

```
    // Read the data from the blob column where the PDF exists
    byte[] byteBuffer = Row.FileData.GetBlobData(0, (int)Row.FileData.Length);

    using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(byteBuffer))
    {

        // Here is the important stuff
        var extractStrategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();

        // This call will extract the page with the proper data on it depending on the exam type
        // 1-page exams = NBOME - need to read first page for exam result data
        // 2-page exams = NBME - need to read second page for exam result data
        // The next two statements utilize this construct.
        var vendor = pdfReader.NumberOfPages == 1 ? "NBOME" : "NBME";

        *** THIS NEXT LINE GIVES THE EMPTY STRING
        var newText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, pdfReader.NumberOfPages == 1 ? 1 : 2, extractStrategy);

        var stringList = newText.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        var fileParser = FileParseFactory.GetFileParse(stringList, vendor);

        // Populate our output variables
        Row.ParsedExamName = fileParser.GetExamName(stringList);
        Row.DateParsed = DateTime.Now;
        Row.ParsedId = fileParser.GetStudentId(stringList);
        Row.ParsedTestDate = fileParser.GetTestDate(stringList);
        Row.ParsedTestDateString = fileParser.GetTestDateAsString(stringList);
        Row.ParsedName = fileParser.GetStudentName(stringList);
        Row.ParsedTotalScore = fileParser.GetTestScore(stringList);
        Row.ParsedVendor = vendor;
    }
```

This is not for all PDFs, by the way.  To explain more, we are reading in exam files.  One of the exam types (NBME) seems to be reading just fine.  However, the other type (NBOME) is not.  However, prior to this week, the NBOME ones were being read fine.

This leads me to think it is an internal format change of the PDF file itself.

Also, another bit of information is that the actual pdfReader has data - I can get a byte[] array of the data - but the call to get any text is simply giving me empty.

I'm sorry I'm not able to show any exam data or files - that information is sensitive.

Has anybody seen something like this?  If so, any possible solutions?

Comment: Are you by any chance a customer of iText Software? Then you can securely submit a PDF, we can even sign an NDA if you want.

Comment: otherwise you simply *have to share* an example PDF to illustrate the issue. There are numerous ways to make text not extractable from a PDF. Actually only PDFs which (implicitly or explicitly) have been created with tools that support text extraction can be used as a good source for text extraction tools. Fortunately many tools implicitly generate extractable text content.

Answer (score 1):

Well - we have found our answer.  The user was originally going to the NBOME web site and downloading the PDF exam result files to import into my parsing system.  Like I said, this worked for quite some time.  Recently (this week), however, the user started not downloading the files, but using a PDF printing feature and printed the PDF files as PDF.  When she did that, the problem occurred.

Bottom line, it looks like the printing the PDF as PDF may have been injecting some characters or something under the covers that was causing the reading of the PDF via iTextSharp to not fail, but to give an empty string.  She should have just continued downloading them directly.

Thanks to those who offered some comments!

Comment: Ypu talk about "the user" and it sounds as if you are using iTextSharp in a commercial context. Are you sure you can use iTextSharp as free software? It kind of sounds as if your company requires a commercial license for its use of iTextSharp.

Comment: The "user" is person in our clinical education department.  We are a non-profit medical school and we use this as a way to download exam scores for our students.  So, there is no "profit" or revenue realized by this product - essentially as a time-saving tool and courtesy to our students to not have to go to the agency administering their exams.